# MySQL incorrect output not sure whats wrong with the query

Tags: mysql

Trying to write and execute a MySQL query to display the movie number, movie title, movie cost, and movie genre for all movies that are either action or comedy movies and that have a cost that is less than $50.  Sort the results in ascending order by genre.

```
mysql> select mv_no, mv_name, mv_cost, mv_genre from movie    
    -> where mv_genre = ('Action' or 'Comedy') and mv_cost < 50    
    -> order by mv_genre;

+-------+----------------------------+---------+----------+
| mv_no | mv_name                    | mv_cost | mv_genre |    
+-------+----------------------------+---------+----------+    
| 1245  | Time to Burn               | 45.49   | ACTION   |    
| 1237  | Beatnik Fever              | 29.95   | COMEDY   |    
| 1239  | Where Hope Dies            | 25.49   | DRAMA    |    
| 1234  | The Cesar Family Christmas | 39.95   | FAMILY   |    
+-------+----------------------------+---------+----------+
4 rows in set, 10 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: its not suppose to show drama or family movies

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
select mv_no, mv_name, mv_cost, mv_genre from movie

where (mv_genre = 'Action' or mv_genre = 'Comedy') and mv_cost < 50

order by mv_genre;
```

Answer (score 0):

Had you tried using an `IN` clause:

```
select mv_no, mv_name, mv_cost, mv_genre 
from movie
where mv_genre in ('Action', 'Comedy') 
  and mv_cost < 50
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6654c/2)

Or you can alter the way that you are using the `OR` clause:

```
select mv_no, mv_name, mv_cost, mv_genre 
from movie
where (mv_genre = 'Action' or mv_genre= 'Comedy') 
  and mv_cost < 50
```

Comment: That's what I was going to recommend. The use of `OR` in the original is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The error appears to be in your wear clause, you could use an `IN` like:

```
WHERE mv_genre IN ('Action', 'Comedy')
```

Your current clause of `mv_genre = ('Action' or 'Comedy')` does not compute to `if the genre is 'Action' or the genre is 'Comedy'` it actually just means that you want to evaluate if `'Action' OR 'Comedy'` is true and then compare the result to `mv_genre` which would never return what you expected it to. You can compare with multiple values easily using `IN` and then a list or you could be more verbose and compare like:

```
WHERE (mv_genre = 'Action' OR mv_genre = 'Comedy')
```

Whichever you prefer and fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be

```
mysql> select mv_no, mv_name, mv_cost, mv_genre from movie
   -> where mv_genre IN ('Action', 'Comedy') and mv_cost < 50
    -> order by mv_genre;
```